# Azure Key Vault with App Service connection error

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to set up a new app slot for my azure website.

Here is my error:

[image]

I've looked at a few articles online and then made sure the app slot was using System assigned identities.

But I still get the above error?

What am I missing?

Here is what it looks like on the Configuration section

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have done the steps below, then it should work.

1.After enabling the system-assigned identity(MSI) of your slot, navigate to your keyvault in the portal -> `Access policies` -> add the MSI of your slot to the access policy with the correct secret permission, just search for your web app name, the MSI of the slot has the format as `webappname/slots/slotname`, details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal).

2.If you use the `SecretUri`, the format of the connection string in your slot should be like below, double-check it.

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://joykeyvault123.vault.azure.net/secrets/encryptionKey/492c7788a9da421c8b9752ef18b53f5d)
```

You could get the `SecretUri` in your secret in the portal.

[image]

It works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: that was it! I was missing the 1. section with adding in the access policies and then searching for the slot name as the principle! I also had to re-add the key vault secret again. Then everything synced up and WORKED!!! Thanks again!